# 4clojure #69 Merge with a Function

Tags: clojure

Here is my solution.

```
(defn mf [f & ms] (
  (let [mm (apply merge ms)
        ks (keys mm)
        rf (fn [koef fc maps] (reduce fc (filter #(not (= % nil)) (map koef maps))))] 
    (into {} (map #(vector % (rf % f ms)) ks)))))
```

When I try to use it, I encounter an error.

```
(mf + {:a 1 :b 2 :d 7} {:a 2 :b 3 :c 6})
```

ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)

However, when I input definitions in repl line by line, everything goes well.

```
>(def f +)
>(def ms '({:a 1 :b 2 :d 7} {:a 2 :b 3 :c 6}))
>(def mm (apply merge ms))
...
>(into {} (map #(vector % (rf % f ms)) ks))
{:c 6, :a 3, :b 5, :d 7}
>
```

What's wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo.  You have an extra pair of parentheses.  It should read:

```
(defn mf [f & ms]
  (let [mm (apply merge ms)
        ks (keys mm)
        rf (fn [koef fc maps] (reduce fc (filter #(not (= % nil)) (map koef maps))))]
    (into {} (map #(vector % (rf % f ms)) ks))))

(mf + {:a 1, :b 2, :d 7} {:a 2, :b 3, :c 6}) 
    => {:a 3, :b 5, :d 7, :c 6}
```